# How can I have Gene name labels on a volcano plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add labels to my volcano plot however, some of the labels do not appear on the VP while some do. Can someone tell me perphaps what the issue is.

For example, in this graph the gene "Nr1h4" is not showing up on the graph and is marked as False instead of True.

```
New.df.7vsNO$genelabels <- ""
New.df.7vsNO$genelabels <- ifelse(New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Shh"
                                  | New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Ascl3"
                                  | New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Klk1b27"
                                  | New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Tenm1"
                                  | New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Nr1h4", T, F)

                
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
                          
ggplot(New.df.7vsNO) + 
  geom_point(aes(log2FC,logpv,col= diffexpressed)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(log2FC, logpv),label = ifelse(New.df.7vsNO$genelabels == TRUE, as.character(New.df.7vsNO$Genes),""), box.padding = unit(.7, "lines"),hjust= 0.30) + 
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),text = element_text(size= 13))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```

My data:

```
structure(list(log2FC = c(2.5576, -1.7629, 4.5593, -1.6414, 4.7747, 
1.9217, 2.5951, -2.4236, 4.2056, -2.8089, -2.1215, -1.7551, 7.6618, 
1.9732, 1.768, -1.7532, 2.1137, -7.4119, -5.0595, -1.6435), logpv = c(6.23062267392386, 
2.4454139371159, 6.87289520163519, 2.41294040382783, 9.84466396253494, 
3.31880400398931, 5.49214412830417, 5.38090666937326, 10.3914739664228, 
7.39254497678533, 4.19928292171762, 2.43023996241365, 3.67370511218151, 
3.17656489822122, 2.45950785169463, 2.70542356079838, 3.13990167030148, 
3.04151256697968, 14.8041003475908, 2.43438827509794), diffexpressed = c("UP", 
"DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", 
"DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", 
"DOWN"), Genes = c("Ngfr", "Axin2", "Igsf5", "Dlat", "Scnn1g", 
"Ckmt1", "Tmprss2", "Pparg", "Sema4f", "Hk2", "Pxmp4", "Scn4a", 
"Slc13a2", "Timp1", "Uhrf1", "Cnn1", "Ube2c", "Rhbg", "Tmem79", 
"Cyp51"), genelabels = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your plot is fine. What is happening is that your dataset does not have any of the genes you specified in the `ifelse` statement. If you check your dataset for the genes, it returns `charachter(0)`, i.e., there's no such genes in the dataset.

```
New.df.7vsNO$Genes[New.df.7vsNO$Genes %in% c("Shh", "Ascl3", "Klk1b27", 
                                             "Tenm1", "Nr1h4")]
```

But if you plot other genes, it works:

```
New.df.7vsNO$genelabels <- ifelse(New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Ngfr"
                                  | New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Axin2"
                                  | New.df.7vsNO$Genes == "Igsf5", T, F)
ggplot(New.df.7vsNO) + 
      geom_point(aes(log2FC,logpv,col= diffexpressed)) +
      geom_text_repel(aes(log2FC, logpv),
                      label = ifelse(New.df.7vsNO$genelabels == TRUE, 
                                     as.character(New.df.7vsNO$Genes),""), 
                      box.padding = unit(.7, "lines"),hjust= 0.30) + 
      theme(legend.title=element_blank(),text = element_text(size= 13))+
      scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```

[image: Vulcano Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(New.df.7vsNO) + 
  geom_point(aes(log2FC,logpv,col= diffexpressed)) +
  geom_text_repel(data = New.df.7vsNO %>% 
                    filter(Genes %in% c("Ngfr", "Axin2", "Igsf5", "Dlat", "Tmem79", "Hk2")), 
            aes(label = Genes, x = log2FC, y = logpv), box.padding = unit(.7, "lines"),hjust= 0.30) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]